# Integers don't show when written into .dat file in c

Tags: c

I am trying to write some records (patient info) into a .dat file using c. The patient info contains the National ID no., name, gender and the telephone no.

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char order = 'y';
int nic = 0; // NIC no.
char name[] = "xxx"; // name
char gender = 'x'; // Patients' gender
int tel_no = 0; // telephone no.

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("patientdetails.dat", "w"); // Creat patientdetails file

if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot open file\n");
    return -1;
}
else
{
    printf("Do you want to enter a record (y/n): ");
    scanf("%c", &order);

    while (order == 'y' || order == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Enter nic no.: ");
        scanf("%d", &nic);

        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", name);

        printf("Enter gender (m/f): ");
        scanf(" %c", &gender);

        printf("Enter tel no.: ");
        scanf("%d", &tel_no);

        fprintf(fp, "%d %s %c %d\n", nic, name, gender, tel_no);

        printf("Do you want to enter a record (y/n): ");
        scanf(" %c", &order);
    }
    fclose(fp);

}

return 0;
}
```

However when I enter the following info into my .dat file in the terminal:

```
Do you want to enter a record (y/n): y
Enter nic no.: 200007102766
Enter name: Timothy
Enter gender (m/f): m
Enter tel no.: 0779428897
Do you want to enter a record (y/n): n
```

There is an error in the integers, namely nic no. and telephone no.

Additionally I made another program to read the file, the error in the integers still seem to show up.

Errors in the .dat file:

7956596 Timothy m 779428897

I can't seem to figure out how to correct the integer errors,
where 20007102766 is shown as 7956596
and 0779428897 is shown as 779428897.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The variable `nic` is a signed type and it can't hold the value you are asking to assign

Comment: `20007102766` is too large for a 32-bit int, you'd need to use a larger type to store it as a number. You'd most likely be better off storing the phone number as a string.

Comment: Telephone numbers are no integers. You are not able to preserve the correct number of leading zeros when you treat them as integers. You should treat them as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable byte size is larger than a int, so you should use bigger variable type.
In your example, you can use **long** type for nic and tel_no veriables.

Also you should use **%ld** in format, otherwise it gives you warning.

```
char order = 'y';
long nic = 0; // NIC no.
char name[] = "xxx"; // name
char gender = 'x'; // Patients' gender
long tel_no = 0; // telephone no.
```

And while formating

```
 printf("Enter nic no.: ");
        scanf("%ld", &nic);
printf("Enter tel no.: ");
        scanf("%ld", &tel_no);
fprintf(fp, "%ld %s %c %ld\n", nic, name, gender, tel_no);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. It seems that the id is too large for the long type as well. I was thinking of treating both the ID and the tel no. as strings.

Comment: entering each of the fields as char strings would be the most portable way and the easiest to read back out of the file